# How to group strings with similar beginnings in a sorted list?

Tags: python, diff, hierarchy

Given this:

```
['2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-01',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-02',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-03',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-04',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-05',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-06',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-07',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-08',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-09',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-10',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-11',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-12',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-13',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-14',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-15',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-16',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-17',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-18',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-19',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-20',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-21',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-22',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-23',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-24',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-25',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-26',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-27',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-28',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-29',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-30',
 '2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-31',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-01',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-02',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-03',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-04',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-05',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-06',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-07',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-08',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-09',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-10',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-11',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-12',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-13',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-14',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-15',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-16',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-17',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-18',
 '2014\\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-19']
```

How do you get something like this? (Solution 1: delimiter based, with user definable delimiter)

```
['2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-01',
 '                 \\2014-01-02',
 '                 \\2014-01-03',
 '                 \\2014-01-04',
 '                 \\2014-01-05',
 '                 \\2014-01-06',
 '                 \\2014-01-07',
 '                 \\2014-01-08',
 '                 \\2014-01-09',
 '                 \\2014-01-10',
 '                 \\2014-01-11',
 '                 \\2014-01-12',
 '                 \\2014-01-13',
 '                 \\2014-01-14',
 '                 \\2014-01-15',
 '                 \\2014-01-16',
 '                 \\2014-01-17',
 '                 \\2014-01-18',
 '                 \\2014-01-19',
 '                 \\2014-01-20',
 '                 \\2014-01-21',
 '                 \\2014-01-22',
 '                 \\2014-01-23',
 '                 \\2014-01-24',
 '                 \\2014-01-25',
 '                 \\2014-01-26',
 '                 \\2014-01-27',
 '                 \\2014-01-28',
 '                 \\2014-01-29',
 '                 \\2014-01-30',
 '                 \\2014-01-31',
 '    \\2014-02 Feb\\2014-02-01',
 '                 \\2014-02-02',
 '                 \\2014-02-03',
 '                 \\2014-02-04',
 '                 \\2014-02-05',
 '                 \\2014-02-06',
 '                 \\2014-02-07',
 '                 \\2014-02-08',
 '                 \\2014-02-09',
 '                 \\2014-02-10',
 '                 \\2014-02-11',
 '                 \\2014-02-12',
 '                 \\2014-02-13',
 '                 \\2014-02-14',
 '                 \\2014-02-15',
 '                 \\2014-02-16',
 '                 \\2014-02-17',
 '                 \\2014-02-18',
 '                 \\2014-02-19']
```

I encounter this situation quite often, basically I have a list of strings that I want to make it easier to process visually by removing redundant matching elements at the beginning of the string. Now I know this is what a TREE output is for normal folder traversal, but these are not real folders, but just strings in a list.

Ideally the function would accept a heirarchy delimiter or just do on a character basis (seperator=None).

```
def printheirarchy(data,seperator=","):
```

The output for a character level hierarchy would be like following: (Solution 2: character by character)

```
['2014\\2014-01 Jan\\2014-01-01',
 '                            2',
 '                            3',
 '                            4',
 '                            5',
 '                            6',
 '                            7',
 '                            8',
 '                            9',
 '                           10',
 '                            1',
 '                            2',
 '                            3',
 '                            4',
 '                            5',
 '                            6',
 '                            7',
 '                            8',
 '                            9',
 '                           20',
 '                            1',
 '                            2',
 '                            3',
 '                            4',
 '                            5',
 '                            6',
 '                            7',
 '                            8',
 '                            9',
 '                           30',
 '                            1',
 '            2 Feb\\2014-02-01',
 '                            2',
 '                            3',
 '                            4',
 '                            5',
 '                            6',
 '                            7',
 '                            8',
 '                            9',
 '                           10',
 '                            1',
 '                            2',
 '                            3',
 '                            4',
 '                            5',
 '                            6',
 '                            7',
 '                            8',
 '                            9']
```

This seems less useful in this example but is very evident when analyzing urls, logs ...etc. Ideally you would just grey out the similar parts, rather than remove them, but I don't even know how to begin with that. (or conversely, bold the differences). Basically you are comparing each element with the previous element and highlighting differences & suppressing similarities.

I've searched and found many options that are close to this, but not exactly this. `os.path.commonprefix` is an example. Maybe difflib?

The value is in reducing visual clutter when examining lists of items.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe if you showed us what you've tried. This has the potential of being a __great__ question.

Comment: This looks like a job for a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Perhaps [datrie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datrie/)? If you know the length of the prefix ahead of time you might be able to find a more efficient solution for the specific case.

Comment: It might improve the question if you supply *less* sample data. After the first 10 or so lines you get to diminishing returns.

Comment: do you actually want the output to be in the format of whitespace prefixed strings? or that was just to illustrate?

Comment: How about making a dictionary, where each key is the first element in your list and the value is a list of elements in the format you've described?

Comment: I have the same question as Erik. Changing this to be nested dictionaries could be a nice way to store the data. Edit: @msvalkon - looks like we had the same thought at the same time!

Comment: @kojiro i wanted to be sure that Feb was included in the data as well... I guess I could delete the rest of jan entries.

Comment: @msvalkon I can't change the data, I often receive it as just a simple list and want to feed it in directly.

Comment: @ErikAllik to show hierarchy and make it easy to visually distinguish they should line up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question.  How about this small solution:

```
def commonPrefix(a, b):
  i = 0
  while i < len(a) and i < len(b) and a[i] == b[i]:
    i += 1
  return i

def eachWithPrefix(v):
  p = ''
  for x in v:
    yield commonPrefix(p, x), x
    p = x
```

Now you can choose what you want:

```
list(eachWithPrefix(v))
```

will return a list of your values and each will state how many characters are equal to the former line, so

```
print '\n'.join(' '*p + x[p:] for p, x in eachWithPrefix(v))
```

Will print the second solution you proposed.

```
print '\n'.join('\t' * p + '\\'.join(x[p:]) for p, x in eachWithPrefix(x.split('\\') for x in v))
```

on the other hand will perform the same action for the delimiter `\` and replace the to-be-omitted parts with tab stops.  This is not *quite* the format you proposed in your first output example but I guess you get the point.

Try:

```
print '\n'.join('\\'.join([ s if i >= p else ' '*len(s) for i, s in enumerate(x) ]) for p, x in eachWithPrefix(x.split('\\') for x in v))
```

This will replace the equal parts with like-sized just-space strings.  The output will still contain the delimiters, though, but maybe that's even nicer:

```
2014\2014-01 Jan\2014-01-01
    \           \2014-01-02
    \           \2014-01-03
    \           \2014-01-04
    \           \2014-01-05
...
    \           \2014-01-31
    \2014-02 Feb\2014-02-01
    \           \2014-02-02
    \           \2014-02-03
...
```

To remove also those you can use this approach:

```
print '\n'.join(' ' * len('\\'.join(x[:p])) + '\\'.join(x)[len('\\'.join(x[:p])):] for p, x in eachWithPrefix(x.split('\\') for x in v))
```

But this now contains some code doubling, so maybe an iterative loop would be nicer here:

```
for p, x in eachWithPrefix(x.split('\\') for x in v):
  s = '\\'.join(x)
  c = '\\'.join(x[:p])
  print ' '*len(c) + s[len(c):]
```

Or as an easy-to-use generator:

```
def heirarchy(data, separator=","):
  for p, x in eachWithPrefix(x.split(separator) if separator else list(x) for x in data):
    s = separator.join(x)
    c = separator.join(x[:p])
    yield ' '*len(c) + s[len(c):]
```

So now `heirarchy(data, separator='\\')` creates exactly your expected output.

Comment: I just tested this and this is great! It does work except for the whole tab thing, that makes it look wonky.

Comment: You can of course replace the parts in the lists with equally-sized strings of spaces and join all that.  I'll provide this, just a second ...

Comment: Yes it works now, but @qarma's answer doesn't have the "\" in the name.

Comment: I added some more code using my solution to create exactly what was wanted.

Comment: Thank you! That works as expected! I suggest you remove the other parts, and leave the loop in, so yours is the first answer to handle both the cases. It will need to be refactored a bit to make it a function which is easy to use though.

Comment: I did the refactoring for you ;-)  Just call `list(heirarchy(data, '\\'))` to get the list you expected.  I couldn't bring me to name that `printheirarchy` as you proposed, though, since it doesn't print anything.

Comment: I even added a tiny code change to allow use of separator `''` in case you want to use single characters (i. e. no delimiters) to get the second output.

Comment: Hahaha, that's exactly what I was working on right now and was going to suggest it to you after i was done, but you are much faster!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you want to reinvent a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Anyhow, here's a simple generator:

```
def grouped(iterable):
    prefix = None
    for i in iterable:
        pre, suf = i[:16], i[16:]
        if pre != prefix:
            prefix = pre
            yield pre + suf
        else:
            yield " " * 16 + suf
```

Comment: hit enter too fast, here it is

Comment: I can confirm this works for the separator case. by where are you specifying the seperator? Can I change it?

Comment: I have no idea how this works. Can't make sense of it, even after reading on wikipedia. Can you explain a bit more? How does splitting the string by 16 characters get all this magical stuff to happen? And can you get it working for character by character case as well?

Comment: That splitting by 16 characters "works" (or rather "seems to work") because your common prefix is often 16 characters long.  Not in all cases (day change is not handled properly), though, so I must conclude that this is not even a working solution.

Comment: I've tried it though and it does work exactly for case 1. But you are saying it won't work for any other example? That's a good point

Answer (score 1):

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def remove_redundant_prefixes(it):
    """
    remove_redundant_prefixes(it) -> iterable (generator)

        Iterate through a list of strings, removing successive common prefixes.
    """
    prev_line = ''
    for line in sorted(it):
        sm = SequenceMatcher(a=prev_line, b=line)
        prev_line = line

        # Returns 3 element tuple, last element is the size of the match.
        match_size = sm.get_matching_blocks()[0][2]

        # No match == no prefix, don't prune the string.
        if match_size == 0:
            yield line
        else:
            # Prune per the match
            yield line.replace(line[:match_size], ' ' * match_size, 1)
```

Comment: I can confirm that your answer works for the character by character case as well, but not for the separator case

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand the separator case.

Comment: Suppose I want to consider similarities upto a separator only, i.e. between seperators, a token is taken as a whole and not it's individual characters. So if the whole is not identical then it stays. Like in the question above, the separator is "\" (shown as "\\", due to string escaping)

Answer (score 0):

Ok inspired by the commonprefix answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718196/python-determine-prefix-from-a-set-of-similar-strings) I played it with it for a bit and inspiration came when I realized I could send a list with just two elements each time!

Here's my code, this handles only the character by character case, and I'm not sure how good this is (i suspect not very much! as a lot of unnecessary copying occurs). But I was able to successfully reproduce the 3rd output from my question. This still leaves the other part unresolved.

```
def printheirarchy(data,seperator=","):
    if len(data) < 2:
        pprint(data)
        return
    newdata = []
    newdata.append(data[0])
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
        prefix = os.path.commonprefix(data[i-1:i+1])
        newdata.append(data[i].replace(prefix," "*len(prefix),1))
    pprint(newdata)
```