# Python finding the common parts of a string throughout a list and removing it from every item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of file directories that looks similar to this:

```
path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file2.txt
path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/B/file7.txt
path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file1.txt
path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/C/file5.txt
```

I am trying to remove the **beginnings** of the paths that are the **same** from every list, and then deleting that from each file.

The list can be any length, and in the example I would be trying to change the list into:

```
A/file2.txt
B/file7.txt
A/file1.txt
C/file5.txt
```

Methods like `re.sub(r'.*I', 'I', filepath)` and `filepath.split('_', 1)[-1]` can be used for the replacing, but I'm not sure about how to find the common parts in the list of filepaths

Note:

I am using Windows and python 3

Comment: So what have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it? Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited the question now to include some code. I have made it clearer of what I know what to do and what I am still unsure of as well.

Comment: The Q has been edited to be more focussed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **first part** of the answer is here: [Python: Determine prefix from a set of (similar) strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718196/python-determine-prefix-from-a-set-of-similar-strings)

Use `os.path.commonprefix()` to find the longest common (first part) of the string

The code for selecting the part of the list that is the same as from that answer is:

```
# Return the longest prefix of all list elements.
def commonprefix(m):
    "Given a list of pathnames, returns the longest common leading component"
    if not m: return ''
    s1 = min(m)
    s2 = max(m)
    for i, c in enumerate(s1):
        if c != s2[i]:
            return s1[:i]
    return s1
```

Now all you have to do is use slicing to remove the resulting string from each item in the list

This results in:

```
# Return the longest prefix of all list elements.
def commonprefix(m):
    "Given a list of pathnames, returns the longest common leading component"
    if not m: return ''
    s1 = min(m)
    s2 = max(m)
    for i, c in enumerate(s1):
        if c != s2[i]:
            ans = s1[:i]
            break
    for each in range(len(m)):
        m[each] = m[each].split(ans, 1)[-1]
    return m
```

Comment: the slice and removal would be better as different function rather than tacked on to end of "commonprefix".

Answer (score 1):

As the input list contains not just a strings but filenames it seems reasonable to me to consider the common prefix among all filepaths only as a ***whole-word*** sequences/sections.

Let's say one of the filepaths is `path/new/stuff2/files/morefiles/C/file5.txt`. 
The common prefix is determined as `path/new/stuff`, but the 3rd section `stuff2` will be breaked at the last character `2`.
So that the lastly mentioned `commonprefix()` implementation will cut such filepath to `2/files/morefiles` making it broken and non-accessible(in terms of *filesystem*). In such case it would be reasonable to cut only the first common ***whole-word*** sections (i.e. `path/new/`).

---

The solution using `zip()` function and `set` object:
The input list of filepaths was slightly modified for demonstration purpose: the last filepath differs on 3rd section `.../stuffall/...`:

```
paths = [
    'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file2.txt', 'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/B/file7.txt',
    'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file1.txt', 'path/new/stuffall/files/morefiles/C/file5.txt'
]
c_prefix = ''  # common filpath prefix

for i in zip(*paths):
    s = set(i)
    if len(s) == 1:
        c_prefix += s.pop()
    else:
        if c_prefix:
            # considering only the whole-word sections as a common parts
            paths = [ p.replace(c_prefix if c_prefix.endswith('/') else c_prefix[:c_prefix.rfind('/')+1] , '')
                      for p in paths ]
        break

print(paths)
```

The output:

```
['stuff/files/morefiles/A/file2.txt', 'stuff/files/morefiles/B/file7.txt', 'stuff/files/morefiles/A/file1.txt', 'stuffall/files/morefiles/C/file5.txt']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the paths around `'/'`, use `zip_longest` to avoid cutting long paths and to transpose the paths.

You can then remove the common elements, `zip` again to transpose the paths and join them with `'/'`:

```
paths = ['path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file2.txt',
'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/B/file7.txt',
'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file1.txt',
'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/A/file1/file2.txt',
'path/new/stuff/files/morefiles/C/file5.txt']

from itertools import izip_longest
transposed = list(izip_longest(*[path.split('/') for path in paths]))
print(transposed)
# [('path', 'path', 'path', 'path', 'path'), ('new', 'new', 'new', 'new', 'new'), ('stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff', 'stuff'), ('files', 'files', 'files', 'files', 'files'), ('morefiles', 'morefiles', 'morefiles', 'morefiles', 'morefiles'), ('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('file2.txt', 'file7.txt', 'file1.txt', 'file1', 'file5.txt'), (None, None, None, 'file2.txt', None)]
while len(set(transposed[0])) == 1:
    transposed.pop(0)

print(transposed)
# [('A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('file2.txt', 'file7.txt', 'file1.txt', 'file1', 'file5.txt'), (None, None, None, 'file2.txt', None)]
print(['/'.join(filter(None, path)) for path in zip(*transposed)])
# ['A/file2.txt', 'B/file7.txt', 'A/file1.txt', 'A/file1/file2.txt', 'C/file5.txt']
```

Answer (score -1):

Already answered here [Python: Determine prefix from a set of (similar) strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718196/python-determine-prefix-from-a-set-of-similar-strings)

"Never rewrite what is provided to you": Use `os.path.commonprefix()` to find the longest common prefix, and then slice your strings accordingly.

Comment: Then vote/flag to close as a duplicate, rather than copying content across.